# why does $\lim_{s\to\infty}(\int^{\infty}_{0^+}e^{-st}\frac{df}{dt}dt) =0$

Tags: integration

I am learning Laplace transform and don't understand why does
$$\lim_{s\to\infty}(\int^{\infty}_{0^+}e^{-st}\frac{df}{dt}dt)=0$$

It's in the explanation of initial theorem. Here is what I can get
$$\lim_{s\to\infty}(\int^{\infty}_{0^+}e^{-st}\frac{df}{dt}dt)=\lim_{s\to\infty}(\int^{f(\infty)}_{f(0^+)}e^{-st}df)=\lim_{s\to\infty}(f(0^+))$$

Comment: It's part of the assumptions - the Laplace transform is most effective when it is defined on infinitely differentiable functions whose rate of growth at infinity is not exponential.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $f$ is well-behaved. Partial integration gives

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{0}^{\infty }dt\exp [-st]\partial _{t}f(t) &=&\left\vert \exp
[-st]f(t)\right\vert _{0}^{\infty }+s\int_{0}^{\infty }dt\exp [-st]f(t) \\
&=&f(0^{+})+\int_{0}^{\infty }du\exp [-u]f(\frac{u}{s})
\end{eqnarray*}
Here
\begin{equation*}
\int_{0}^{\infty }du\exp [-u]f(\frac{u}{s})=\int_{0}^{a}du\exp [-u]f(\frac{u%
}{s})+\int_{a}^{\infty }du\exp [-u]f(\frac{u}{s})
\end{equation*}
where both contributions vanish as $s\rightarrow \infty $.